# What honeycomb has the highest volume to edge length ratio?

Tags: optimization, polyhedra, tessellations

This question is analagous to the Kelvin Problem where the solution, the Weaire-Phelan Structure, has the highest volume to surface area ratio; however, the cell volume is compared to edge length instead.

Comment: The biggest one, as the edges' lenghts grow linearly (!) with a scale while the volume increases with a scale's cube.

Comment: This is true. Perhaps, I should have made it clear that, like the Kelvin Problem, the cells of all possible honeycombs must be of a unit volume, or average to thus.

Comment: Or, you might define a criterion as a ratio of a volume to the cube of sum of edge lengths. However then a modification like cutting off an edge, resulting in adding another parallel edge, is a negligible shape modification which substantially changes the coefficient value.

Comment: Then I suppose one would have to construct a biggest possible single cell (whatever shape fills the 3D space).